# Merge Mozilla Addon to Build

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla, firefox-developer-tools

I am working on a few addons on Mozilla since this easier than manually editing the source code.

The bigger picture is to have a customized browser that I can share with my fellow geeks and friends.

**Question**:Is there a simple way to add an addon to a Mozilla build so that my users don't have to manually install the addons on their computer.Something like a pre-packaged Setup.exe. The Setup.exe needs to be fully independent and not requiring to have Mozilla pre-installed.

More info(Edited):

> Another reason is I do not want them to have access to the addons ,
>   the addons shouuld be in the core of the browser.Hence, a user should
>   not be able to turn off or even know it is an addon but barely the
>   functionality of their browser X.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Portable Firefox, make your customizations and share the folder with your friends.

http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable

Comment: I have edited my question which renders this answer as not suitable.But thanks for your contribution.